# Installing AUCTeX on Windows 10

Tags: windows, emacs, auctex

I am following the detailed instructions on how to install AUCTeX on Windows found [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Installation-under-MS-Windows.html#Installation-under-MS-Windows)

After all prerequisites are installed the instructions state to "start some shell (typically Bash) capable of running *configure*"

As I'm running windows, command prompt does not have the configure command and I don't know much about Powershell but I don't think that would work either.

What would be the appropriate solution for running Bash type shell in Windows so as to install AUCTeX as per instructions?

Would activating the window subsystem for Linux featuring Windows 10 be a viable solution? Or is there an alternative, easier or better way? The more straightforward and foolproof the better! :)

edit1: as far as I know, emacs for windows and its dependencies downloaded on the GNU website does not include the AUCTeX package as part of the installation.

Comment: @ArashEsbati OK I'll delete the comment, I don't recall installing it separately but perhaps I did, been a while since I set up this machine:-)

Comment: @ArashEsbati nope I have a cygwin X emacs from cygwin and a native windows emacs from probably main gnu site, but I was probably on auto-pilot when I installed both, haven't had a machine without emacs since 1987...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Reading that you have ever used any other editor would be surprising :-)

Answer (score 5):

As well as posting the question here I also contacted the developers of AUCTeX directly.

I received a reply stating that the AUCTeX installation instructions for Windows provided on the GNU website should be rewritten and updated.

The developer stated that "*Emacs comes with a package manager these days, and AUCTeX is available from there.
So if you get an Emacs installed and do:

**M-x package-list-packages RET**

you should be able to find AUCTeX in that list and install it*"

Problem solved :)

Comment: This procedure is actually described in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Installation): **1.2 Installing AUCTeX:**
The modern and strongly recommended way of installing AUCTeX is by using the Emacs package manager integrated in Emacs 24 and greater (ELPA). Simply do `M-x list-packages RET`, mark the `auctex` package for installation with `i`, and hit `x` to execute the installation procedure. That’s all. This installation procedure has several advantages. Besides being platform and OS independent, you will receive...

Comment: Thanks. I see that now. As a beginner of Emacs I should learn to focus on the manual first and foremost. Google may not be best first port of call for info.